# Running unmanaged EXE in C# sandbox

Tags: c#, unmanaged, sandbox, appdomain, managed

I have a third-party unmanaged program as a part of my application. I have a managed C# application as well which is an "entry point" for the system. It ensures that the unmanaged  program can only be run properly if certain conditions are met.

I'd like to have the C# application run the unmanaged program in a sandbox so that a particular file isn't *directly* read from or written to the hard drive; instead the C# app needs to process it and then feed the file to the 3rd-party application or save it to the disk.

I've looked into using the AppDomain class of C# but I believe only managed code can be run by it. Is there an alternative system for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need a hypervisor/VM.  C# doesn't have any control over the .EXE once it is launched.

Comment: This kind of functionality requires an OS hook/extension and would take a lot of time; you also probably can't do it in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't really run an unmanaged program in a C# sandbox, save for writing an unmanaged emulator in C# and running the unmanaged executable in that.  And it'd be slow to run and hard to write so you probably don't want to go that route.

The only way I could see this working would be if the unmanaged program called a C# wrapper for the file system.  Do you have the source code for the unmanaged program?

Comment: I do have the source code for it but the build setup is rather flaky and I'm not sure if it's practical to manage the code. It does build with visual studio 2008 (C++) but I'm not sure if it's a simple matter of adding a few extra compiler directives to the makefiles.

Comment: @FranklinBarnett - That would be a separate question that would involve you posting the code in question.  Why are you trying to do a sandbox if you don't know how to do a sandbox?

Comment: @Ramhound A sandbox is  the only real option I see here. The question isn't so much how to make a sandbox, but moreso whether the pre-built C# AppDomain "sandbox" can sandbox unmanaged code. Because the answer is no (according to this answer), I may need to figure out how to get the other program to compile as managed code.

Comment: @FranklinBarnett - Just not sure the reason you are worried about sandboxing at this point.  Its perfectly possible to write safe unmanaged code without it. Let the operating system handle all that.

Comment: @Ramhound The reason for the sandbox is so that files read/written by a certain unmanaged app are processed through my program before they are read by that program or before they are written to the hard drive. It appears that method isn't possible using C#.